# Set pivot filter to an existing pivot table with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

One all three months I need to create excel sheets for all cost centers in my company. For this I have one original excel file with a pivot in it and for every cost center I need to set the filter of the pivot on the current cost center and save it under the name of the cost center. So I thought I would write a script with apache poi where I first read the original file change the pivot filter to the requested cost center and save the file so I can safe me a lot of work. But if I want to loop through all pivot filters in my table I only see one of 20.

```
   public void createKostenFiles() {

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\bglaus\\Documents\\RFC_2023.01_Kosten_.xlsx");
            Workbook w = new XSSFWorkbook();

            w = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            for (Kostenstelle k : kostenstellen) {
                Workbook workbook = w;
                XSSFSheet s = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet("BI Import");
                XSSFSheet s2 = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet("Last FC");
                XSSFSheet s3 = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet("BI Gebuchte Fixkosten");
                XSSFPivotTable pvt = s.getPivotTables().get(0);
                for (CTPivotFilter ct : pvt.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getFilters().getFilterList()) {
                    System.out.println("All: " + ct.toString());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

So my output on the console looks like this:

```
All: <xml-fragment fld="1" type="valueEqual" id="9196" stringValue1="9196 - Kletter Shop 6a plus" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <main:autoFilter ref="A1">
    <main:filterColumn colId="0">
      <main:customFilters>
        <main:customFilter operator="lessThanOrEqual" val="3"/>
      </main:customFilters>
    </main:filterColumn>
  </main:autoFilter>
</xml-fragment>
```

And I get this same output for every cost center what makes sense but why do I only get this one filter on the line?

```
System.out.println("All: " + ct.toString());
```

The pivot table in my excel sheet looks like this:
[my pivotfilters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY8pj.png)

I thought first it only shows me the selected filters but thats not the issue, and I'm also wondering why it is the last filter.